# Modify latex template in Rmarkdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer

Can I modify the default Latex template used by Rmarkdown to compile Rmd files to pdf with the beamer class? 
I am asking because of the difficulties I encounter using `\includepdf` (from the *pdfpages* package). Inspecting the generated tex source suggests that the root problem is the **ignorenonframetext** option in `\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,]{beamer}`. 
(It is not a viable option for me to manually change the tex source each time)

In short: I want to modify the "Rmd beamer Latex template" (if that exists) to change the default *ignorenonframetext*

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but don't forget to set the background colour to transparent, otherwise it will hide the included pdf

Comment: Download it, modify the class options, save it under the name you like and include it in your RMD YAML head via `template: myModifiedTemplate.tex` (You can find the template inside the rmarkdown repo on GitHub).

Comment: You could try with `\beamer@ignorenonframefalse` in your header includes.

Comment: @Schmelzer: Thanks a lot. Would that be rmd/latex/default.tex with the header line: \documentclass[$if(fontsize)$$fontsize$,$endif$$if(lang)$$lang$,$endif$$if(papersize)$$papersize$,$endif$$for(classoption)$$classoption$$sep$,$endfor$]{$documentclass$}
Somehow hidden in classoption?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the template, you can use `\includepdf` like this:

````
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{pdfpages}
  - \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
  - \makeatletter\beamer@ignorenonframefalse\makeatother
---

test

``` {=latex}
\end{frame}
\includepdf[pages=1-10]{example-image-duck}
\begin{frame}
```

test
````

(the line `\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}` is necessary for beamer versions < 3.64, a patch has been added in [9e3bb9](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/074e2eafc35ffa968ddf9c1920596432c39e3bb9))